# Calling functions on an array of object pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, hash

I couldn't find anything similar to this anywhere. I have an array of pointers to objects (a linked list) for a hash table:

```
LinkList * table[TABLE_SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
    table[i] = NULL;
```

In one of my functions for my hash table class, there I need to call the one of the functions on the `LinkList` object in the `table` array. I'm calling it as such:

```
void HashMap::add_customer(string first, string last, string phone) {   
    int hash = get_hash(phone);
    if (table[hash] == NULL) {
        table[hash] = new LinkList;
    }
    table[hash]->add_customer(first, last, phone); // I HATE THIS LINE
}
```

Everything compiles fine, but when I execute the `table[hash]->add_customer()` line in runtime, I get a `Segmentation Fault` error. When this line is commented out, I get no errors, but obviously, I can't add any customers to my hash table. Is this not the right syntax?

Comment: Are you ensuring that each value in the array is initialized to NULL and also set to NULL when an item is removed?

Comment: Do some adds work, and others don't? What happened before the fault?

Comment: They are all initialized to NULL and no removes have happened before this fault happens. This happens everytime `HashMap::add_customer` is called.

Comment: *"This happens everytime HashMap::add_customer is called."* - That is a different statement than *"when I execute the table[hash]->add_customer() line in runtime, I get a Segmentation Fault error"*.  Which is it?  Is it that line that always causes the problem?  If so then it is the dereference causing the fault.

Comment: Also, per the declaration of `table` that you have shown, it is not initialized to all `NULL`'s, so do you do it later?  Why not use `LinkList *table[TABLE_SIZE] = {}`?

Comment: I'm sorry, anytime `HashMap::add_customer` is called this happens. This is also the only place `table[hash]->add_customer()` is called.

Comment: This is what I'm using to initialize: `for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++) table[i] = NULL;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialized your array of pointers to NULL, since they'll be allocated on the stack/heap or wherever with junk values ....

```
LinkList * table[TABLE_SIZE];
memset(table, NULL, sizeof(LinkList *) * TABLE_SIZE);
```

assuming you've initialized correctly then please check your hashes and assert that indeed they are hash < TABLE_SIZE

try this:

```
 int hash = get_hash(phone) % TABLE_SIZE;
```

Comment: Nice catch. Missing modulus operator perhaps?

Comment: Need to modulo on the initialization of the table element too.

Comment: yeah I shouldn't have being focusing just on that line, I guess highlighting threw me off ... thank you. but I did like `// I HATE THIS LINE`

Answer (score 0):

This snippet looks right, for the hash map's behavior. I'd check the add_customer method in your LinkList implementation. Try using your linked lists outside of this hash map, just to make sure they work as intended.

Comment: It's not entirely clear, but if the seg fault is occurring *on that line* then it never even got to the `add_customer` function, dereferencing the pointer is what caused it.

Comment: That's right. I have separate implementation that just uses the LinkList and `add_customer` works fine there. Its just the pointer dereferencing that's giving me issues.

Comment: Yes, but we all we know now is that commenting the line "fixes" it. @Joshua, try using a debugger to follow where the segfault is happening. If you're in an IDE, there are probably nice tools for this already. If you're at a terminal (assuming Unix here), add the -ggdb flag to your compile, then run gdb [executable name here, a.out if you didn't change anything]. It should nicely identify the error location.

Comment: Ok, gotcha, have you run a debugger? (by the way, my explanation there wasn't meant to be condescending, it just sounded like you might possibly be newer to this particular area)

Comment: Also, make sure your pointers are actually null. If your code is unmanaged, that array is just using whatever values were already in that area of member.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LinkList * table[TABLE_SIZE] = {};
```

That nulls out your pointers to begin with.

---

Can you confirm get_hash returns values < TABLE_SIZE? Add an assert or something.